# @JsonProperty("test_id") do not work in springboot @GetMapping

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

My Controller code like:

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public TestOutputDTO getSchedule(@Valid TestInputDTO dto, BindingResult bindingResult) throws JusException {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            ....
        }

        ...
    }
```

TestInputDTO defines like:

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class TestInputDTO {
        @NotNull
        @JsonProperty("test_id")
        private Long testId;
    }
```

http://localhost:8866/test?test_id=1 DO NOT WORK, testId is null.

http://localhost:8866/test?testId=1 WORKS

I want to call this api by **test_id** style.

what can i do with this?

Thakns.

Comment: try this `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)` on top of class

Comment: Did you clean the project? Seems like refresh issue.

Comment: Write a unit test and convert the object into JSON string. verify if the json string reflects test_id. you code seems fine.

Comment: You aren't sending JSON but rather a regular request parameter. Hence using Jackson annotations, which are or JSON serialization, for basic binding is obviously not going to work.

Comment: @Deadpool not work

Comment: @ShaikElias restart and still not work

Comment: @KarthikR can you share you full code? thanks

Comment: @M.Deinum this is a GET method, i can't post a json data. if use POST method, it works fine.

Comment: You aren't getting the point of my comment. You aren't using JSON and hence no JSON (de)serialization. Hence your annotation is useless. What you are using is basic databinding, i.e. map request parameters to an object.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, i now know what you say. and how can i do with this? front end use Lowercase with underlined style, but back end use Camel-Case style.

Comment: By having the correct property on the server side. I.e. `test_id` instead of `testId`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: Add `@RequestBody` to the dto param as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public TestOutputDTO getSchedule(@Valid @RequestBody TestInputDTO dto, BindingResult bindingResult) throws JusException {

    ...
}
```

If it still doesn't work, test your Jackson mapping by writing a unit test and see what's result.

```
@Test
public void testMapping(){
  TestInputDto testInput = new TestInputDto();
  testInputDto.setTestId(1L);
  assertEquals("{ \"test_id\" : 1}", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testInputDto));
}
```